# url decode, decoding data incorrectly

Tags: php, url-encoding

In my project I need to pass a simple and short query in a GET variable, using urlencode.

Some of the characters seem to be get modified after I perform the URL Decode and as a result, no database results are returned.

I was wondering if someone can help me identify why this is and how to troubleshoot this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Before URL Encode:

`((u.firstname LIKE '%Carol%') AND (u.lastname LIKE '%Enriquez%')`

After URL Endode:

`%28%28u.firstname+LIKE+%27%25Carol%25%27%29+AND+%28u.lastname+LIKE+%27%25Enriquez%25%27%29%29++`

After URL Decode:

`((u.firstname LIKE 'Êrol%') AND (u.lastname LIKE '%Enriquez%')`

Comment: It works correctly for me -I copy/pasted your encoded string and got the expected output from `urldecode()`.

Comment: Uh oh... why are you sending SQL snippets in the URL in the first place?! Sounds like a Bad Idea.

Comment: See here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZDER8i

Comment: Looks like you’re decoding it twice.

Comment: Because I need to pass a query between pages. What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: As @Gumbo says - see this: http://codepad.viper-7.com/513Ms6

Comment: Try to encrypt the string with simple 2 way encryption, is more secure than pass only encoded.

Comment: Pass the first name and last name between the pages and then build the query in your application, not forgetting to either escape the parameters or use binds when you build your SQL statements.  Look up "mysql sql injection example php" and you should pretty quickly get the idea...

Comment: I am not decoding twice, maybe it is happening in some indirect way?

Comment: Values in `$_GET` are already URL-decoded by PHP. So there’s no need to pass them through `urldecode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happens if you decode it twice.

Observe: http://3v4l.org/uK5a6

```
var_dump(urldecode(urlencode("((u.firstname LIKE '%Carol%') AND (u.lastname LIKE '%Enriquez%')")));
var_dump(urldecode(urldecode(urlencode("((u.firstname LIKE '%Carol%') AND (u.lastname LIKE '%Enriquez%')"))));

string(64) "((u.firstname LIKE '%Carol%') AND (u.lastname LIKE '%Enriquez%')"
string(62) "((u.firstname LIKE '�rol%') AND (u.lastname LIKE '%Enriquez%')"
```

`%` is a special character used in URL encoding. `%Ca` might be `Ê`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I am 100% I am not calling `urldecod()` twice. The decode function is not in any sort of loop or anything, I wonder why the end result suggests that it is being decoded twice? I believe you are correct, I just don't understand why this is, on my end.

Comment: Keep in mind that GET parameters are decoded for you. So you usually you don't actually need to decode it (again). Be sure to verify this though.

Comment: +1, you are absolutely right! removing the `urldecode()` solved the problem, I guess it was decoded automatically.